# What is meant by binary images of handwritten digits?

Tags: machine-learning, image-processing

I can understand what a handwritten digit is, but what is meant by "binary image"? Can someone explain it?

I am studying machine learning concepts. In doing so, I've come across many types of inputs. For example: binary, continuous, and discrete. The inputs are provided through MNIST handwritten image datasets. In that, I have read about datasets consisting of binary images.

I would also like to know about the difference between greyscale and binary images.

Comment: Is this question about statistics, machine learning, data analysis, data mining, or data visualization? If so, can you please clarify the connection & what you are asking?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about statistics as defined in the [help](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @Glen_b: can you suggest a better stackexchange site for it?

Comment: *Maybe* [dsp](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/), since that includes image processing (but their help about what's on topic isn't [very informative](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a digital representation of the digit in raster (pixel) form, just like the pictures on the Internet you've seen. The additional difference is that the pixels be binary -- black or white, no color or shade of gray.

Comment: Is bilevel image and binary image are different?

Comment: [Same](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_image).

Comment: Thanks. Binary pixels means 0-1. If Grey level included then how pixels will be represented in digits?

Comment: By _binarization_, typically mapping gray levels below a threshold to black, and to white otherwise.

Comment: It seems you would be well served by reading [a book on image processing](http://www.amazon.com/s?field-keywords=image%20processing). These are elementary questions and I'm sure you will have more as you learn.